# How to do left join , same table with different conditions per column

Tags: mysql, join

Hi i need information about how to merge both sentences

Sentence 1

```
select idlote from polizamovtos group by idlote having sum(cargo)-sum(abono) > 0
```

Sentence 2

```
SELECT SUM(cargo) as saldo FROM polizamovtos WHERE FECHAMOVTO='2020-01-01' GROUP BY IDLOTE
```

sentence 1 is the main filter

Hi, I attach more information

table polizamovtos
[image]

**Output expected**

idlote  cargo
1       4000
3       4000
4       5000

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> *Sergio Rossetti* => I need `WHERE FECHAMOVTO='2020-01-01'` only for the second column `saldo`

Test

```sql
SELECT IDLOTE,
       SUM(CASE WHEN FECHAMOVTO='2020-01-01'
                THEN cargo
                ELSE 0
                END) as saldo 
FROM polizamovtos 
GROUP BY IDLOTE
HAVING SUM(cargo) > SUM(abono);
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=13b5b3e25eaacaf473cb4ce5f26dcfcc)

Comment: It is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks, If I want to add another column next the same logic, how it would be? for example a third column

Comment: @SergioRossetti *If I want to add another column next the same logic* I cannot understand what you mean.

Comment: i got it sorry, thanks man.

Answer (score 0):

You can move them together like here

**Schema (MySQL v8.0)**

```
CREATE TABLE polizamovtos  (
  `idlote` VARCHAR(10),
  `cargo` VARCHAR(10),
  `abono` INTEGER,
  `fechamovto` VARCHAR(10)
);

INSERT INTO polizamovtos 
  (`idlote`, `cargo`, `abono`, `fechamovto`)
VALUES
  ('2', '0', '5000', '2019-11-01'),
  ('1', '1000', '0', '2019-12-01'),
  ('2', '4000', '0', '2019-11-01'),
  ('1', '2000', '0', '2020-01-01'),
  ('2', '0', '500', '2020-10-02'),
  ('3', '4000', '0', '2020-01-01'),
  ('4', '5000', '0', '2020-01-01'),
  ('1', '2000', '0', '2020-01-01'),
  ('2',  '0',   '2000', '2020-04-02');
```

---

**Query #1**

```
SELECT 
IDLOTE,
SUM(cargo) as saldo 
FROM polizamovtos 
WHERE FECHAMOVTO='2020-01-01' 
GROUP BY IDLOTE
having sum(cargo)-sum(abono) > 0;

| IDLOTE | saldo |
| ------ | ----- |
| 1      | 4000  |
| 3      | 4000  |
| 4      | 5000  |
```

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/wUqVKNZy96RjR7hTk3md7o/15)

**Query #2**

```
SELECT 
IDLOTE,
SUM(CASE WHEN FECHAMOVTO='2020-01-01' 
    THEN cargo
   ELSE 0
   END) as saldo 
FROM polizamovtos 
GROUP BY IDLOTE
having sum(cargo)-sum(abono) > 0;

| IDLOTE | saldo |
| ------ | ----- |
| 1      | 4000  |
| 3      | 4000  |
| 4      | 5000  |
```

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/wUqVKNZy96RjR7hTk3md7o/16)

Comment: Hi,the problem is that the polizamovtos table has other records that do not have the first criteria: sum (cargo) -sum (abono)> 0;

Comment: I need WHERE FECHAMOVTO='2020-01-01'  only for the second column "saldo"

Comment: @SergioRossetti The output matches to one you post. If there exists some special situation when the provided solution gives wrong output then edit the fiddle and show where the output is wrong and what is the logic of difference.

Comment: as Akina said, you can move the where clause to the sum see updated answer, if you have still problems please add your own data, so that o can chekc it

Comment: Yes i finished the report adding cases thanks a lot..